# Division of integers by bit manipulation

Tags: c++11

"I am trying to divide a integer by bit manipultion and return the quotient. I tried by debugging.At first debugging statement nothing is printed and  at second second statement quotient is zero."

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//function with input arguments a as dividend and b as divisor

int divide(int A, int B) {

 if(A==0)return 0;

int sign = ((A < 0) ^ (B < 0)) ? -1 : 1; 

// remove sign of operands 


  long long a= abs(A); 

 long long b= abs(B); 

 // Initialize the quotient 

   long long quotient = 0, temp = 0; 

// test down from the highest bit and 

// accumulate the tentative value for 

// valid bit 

   for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) { 

   if (temp + (b << i) <= a) { 

 //temp stores the the mutiplier of divisor if it is less than or equal to
//dividend     

    temp += b<< i; 

//updates the quotient    

  quotient |= 1LL << i; 
  cout<<quotient;
         } 
  }cout<<quotient; 

  return (int)(sign*quotient); 
      }


  int main() {divide(-2147483648,-1);

   }


//Expected=2147483647.

//Actual =0
```

Comment: Please turn that code puzzle into a [mre].

Comment: And try compiling your code with `-fsanitize=undefined` then executing it.

Comment: While you are [edit]ing, please apply some consistent indentation. E.g. (but not necessarily): indent by 4 after each `{`, unindent by 4 before each `}`. Put both in the same column and alone on one line. That is my favorite, but anything consistent would be fine.

Comment: Make it `long long a= abs((long long)A);` . The test value you chose, `-2147483648`, is unique in that `abs(-2147483648)` is not representable in `int`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you i found my mistake